# Toggle UIButton Image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to create a `UIButton` that shows text when you are not following something, but when you are it shows text and a checkmark on the right side.

I have been able to achieve this using the following -

```swift
  private(set) var followButton = UIButton(type: .system)

.....

  func setFollowButtonText() {
    let text: String = isFollowing ? "Following" : "Follow"
    let image: UIImage? = isFollowing ? UIImage(systemName: "checkmark") : nil
    followButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
    followButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    followButton.imageToRight()
  }

.....

extension UIButton {
  func imageToRight() {
      transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
      titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
      imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
  }
}
```

However when toggling the state, the checkmark is added but then moves position, it is not smooth and appears to jump slightly to the right.

[image]

How can I prevent this behaviour? I would like the image to either smoothly animate to that final position, or appear in that final position and avoid the jump.

Comment: Can you use a unicode checkmark in your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to give your button a tall enough height constraint so the label does not shift up/down when toggling the checkmark.

To avoid the awkward animation:

```
extension UIButton {
    func imageToRight() {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```